# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting ',' or ')'

Tags: laravel, parsing, laravel-5.5

when trying to migrate in `laravel5.5` I am encountering this problem and I don't know the error.... can anyone help me?
[image]

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting ',' or ')'
```

Comment: Syntax errors are surprisingly difficult to find without knowing anything about the code or your system!

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you if you don't share the code the produces the error? Nobody's psychic here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) And [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You've got a syntax error somewhere in your code. With the information provided, we can't tell you where it is.

Add this method to your `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` file and run your command again. This will give you the full stack trace for your error so that you can track it down.

```
public function renderForConsole($output, Exception $e)
{
    throw $e;
}
```

Don't forget to remove this method when you're done (or keep it if you like, I guess).